# Where would third party resources live in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I have some third party PHP resource that you don't want to conform to a library or a model class.  Is there a defined folder in the CodeIgniter structure for this?  If not, then does that mean it is up to the developer to define their custom folders to put those resources in?

Comment: how about `application/third_party` directory?

Comment: @tomexsans I read about it and it seem to be not what I expected. From their examples, it contains "packages" which seem to be some sort of modular,CI like structure (has controllers, models, view ,etc) that can be reused. See the link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: by the way ,what thirdparty are you using? if not all, some thirdparty packages have a loader or a bootstrap file which you can use on as library and include its files on the thirdparty directory. Or you can make you're own directory that suites your needs,

Comment: Can you find your resource in [Sparkes](http://getsparks.org/)?

Comment: @tomexsans Yeah, I was thinking maybe I have to resort to making my own folder for it.

Comment: sparks is so outdated.

Answer (score 3):

I usually follow this logic:

**application/libraries** -> I put *huge* classes  in here which involve only one file.

**application/helpers** -> I put *small* classes in here which involve only one file.

**application/third_party** -> I put *huge classes or plugins* in here which involve more than one file.